# justified text in anchor tag of list element

Tags: html, css

Short Question… How can i justify the text in an anchor tag?
[JsFiDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bigbigHase/h6nye95o/)

HTML

```
<li>
    <a>
        Text
    </a>
</li>
```

CSS

```
li {width:200px;text-align:justify;}
span {text-align:justify;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have enough amount of text to see it. Updated http://jsfiddle.net/h6nye95o/1/

Otherwise, You might be interested in using `word-spacing` and `letter-spacing` to create some gaps in between the words/letters.